# Power BI count rows with same ID

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to count my rows but I've got a little issue. some rows have the same ID and I don't want to count those again, it's like each row represents a product but some products have the same ID. I'm trying to count the products from Their ids.
is there any measure to apply?

I've used the measure "Countrows" but as I said I've got a lot of Duplicated IDS .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCTCOUNT`:

```
MyMeasure = DISTINCTCOUNT ( MyTable[ProductID] )
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your time. Yes I've used the same solution was just curious if there's anything else that I can apply.

Comment: Why do you need something else, if that gives you what you need? You should include in your question all the things you've tried, and why they don't work for you.

Comment: you're totally right, I should off added my methods that I implemented, to answer your question, I'm an autodidact, I'm still in the process of learning about BI. other than that thank you for your time one more time, I really appreciate it.